# Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph in bbl bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, line-breaking, boxes, ieeetran

Just after the word resonance it is getting the above error. underfull. I have tried using `\smallskip` `\bigskip` but it does not work. In texstudio the author name until the word resonance in one line. What is the solution please?

```
% Generated by IEEEtran.bst, version: 1.14 (2015/08/26)
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\providecommand{\url}[1]{#1}
\csname url@samestyle\endcsname
\providecommand{\newblock}{\relax}
\providecommand{\bibinfo}[2]{#2}
\providecommand{\BIBentrySTDinterwordspacing}{\spaceskip=0pt\relax}
\providecommand{\BIBentryALTinterwordstretchfactor}{4}
\providecommand{\BIBentryALTinterwordspacing}{\spaceskip=\fontdimen2\font plus
\BIBentryALTinterwordstretchfactor\fontdimen3\font minus
  \fontdimen4\font\relax}
\providecommand{\BIBforeignlanguage}[2]{{%
\expandafter\ifx\csname l@#1\endcsname\relax
\typeout{** WARNING: IEEEtran.bst: No hyphenation pattern has been}%
\typeout{** loaded for the language `#1'. Using the pattern for}%
\typeout{** the default language instead.}%
\else
\language=\csname l@#1\endcsname
\fi
#2}}
\providecommand{\BIBdecl}{\relax}
\BIBdecl

\bibitem{Khawaldeh2017}
S.~Khawaldeh, U.~Pervaiz, A.~Rafiq, and R.~Alkhawaldeh, ``{Noninvasive Grading  of Glioma Tumor Using Magnetic Resonance Imaging with Convolutional Neural Networks},'' \emph{Applied Sciences}, vol.~8, no.~1, p.~27, 2017. 


\end{thebibliography}
```

[image: error]

Comment: Is it ok now? Thank you for your quick fix and answer. Appreciate.

Comment: How do i produce MWEB ? I cannot figure out.